# Data Visualization Barplot using seaborn

Tags: python

I want to display a barplot using seaborn. The name, number of categories to display on the x-axis is large and they are getting jumbled together. What can I do to present the categories in a clean way?

Comment: You should Add screenshots of the Current plot for users to Understand your Question Better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using seaborn ser, to change the scale of the font

```
sns.set(font_scale = 2)
```

Comment: That is increasing the font rather than accomodating the categories

Comment: Ok, I didn't get the question right. I think you should rotate the labels, so they can be more readable try using  set_xticklabels(rotation=90)

Answer (score 0):

I have understand your problem like this way,
You want to display all category name of respective column on x-axis.

So, for that follow bellow code snippet and put
x = category column
y = numeric data

```
#import libraries
import seaborn as sns # for data visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # for data visualization

#load tips DataFrame
tips_df =  sns.load_dataset("tips")

plt.figure(figsize = (200, 9)) # barblot size in 200:9 ratio

# plot barplot in horizontal order
sns.barplot(x = tips_df.tip, y = tips_df.total_bill, orient = "h")
```

[click here to see result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIUyq.png)

I suggest you draw seaborn barplot horizontal. It will show proper way.

```
plt.figure(figsize = (9, 200)) # barblot size in 9:200 ratio
# plot barplot in vertical order
sns.barplot(x = tips_df.total_bill, y = tips_df.tip, orient = "v")
```

I hope you will satisfy with above solution.
I recommended you follow [seaborn barplot tutorial](https://indianaiproduction.com/seaborn-barplot) for better understanding. This is neat and clear to  understand.